# What would this set look like $\{x^2+1 \in \Bbb{N} : x \in \Bbb{Z}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am struggling to understand how the ':' works in $\{x^2+1 \in \Bbb{N} : x \in \Bbb{Z}\}$

Comment: I am not sure what you don't understand.  $x^2 + 1$ is always a positive integer..

Comment: You can also think of it as the image of the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means : take the set of all numbers $x^2+1$ where $x$ ranges over all possible values in $\mathbb{Z}$, and put it in the set if $x^2+1 \in \mathbb{N}$, which is always the case here, so the "$\in \mathbb{N}$"-part is superfluous here. It makes it explicit we want a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ obtained in the above way.
So it's just the set $\{1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, \ldots\}$ (assuming an intelligent reader, the $\ldots$ should be clear), but your original notation is more explicit.

We could also have written:

$$\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists z \in \mathbb{Z}: n = z^2 + 1\}$$

for that same set.